MOBILE - SAFARI : Preventing scroll reset to top on mobile when applying fixed position to body
I have a pop up on my website, it can go from hidden, to minimized, to fullscreen states, when on fullscreen, i obviously want to block the scroll of the page behind. So i add and remove the noscroll class when on fullscreen :
  .noscroll {
    height: 100vh;
    height: 100svh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

It works as sa charm on desktop but on mobile-safari, when the noscroll class is added, the body's scroll position gets resetted to the top.
I've tried online the solutions including :

adding a position: fixed to the noscroll class -> not working in my case;
saving the scrollPosition to add it again once the popup is removed ->  like on twitter or instagram, when we reach the top of the page, the app searches for new content, this is triggered everytime i open the popup, i need to avoid that and resetting the scroll position after it happened doesn't solves my problem

Isn't there a way to simply prevent the body from jumping up while still preventing it from scrolling !?

Had the exact same issue, for me the solution was to target the html instead of the body with
overflow: hidden

Hope it solves your issue !
